# Where does mysqldbexport put files on windows?

Tags: mysql

About an hour ago I ran the following:

```
mysqldbexport.exe --server=root:mypword@localhost --export=DATA --bulk-insert mydbname
```

Since that time I've been feeling like an idiot while scouring the internet, and the hard drive...trying to figure out where the results are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I never did find the documentation...but, did run across a statement that says:

> "If table definitions are included in the export, they are written to
>   stdout as usual."

So, I modified my above command to print to a file...which worked.

```
mysqldbexport.exe --server=root:mypword@localhost --export=DATA --bulk-insert mydbname >>c:\temp\mysqlexport.txt
```

Comment: I'm running this on Ubuntu and I found that mysqldbexport writes out to current directory.

The command I executed: mysqldbexport --server=usrname:password@hostname --format=tab --export=data --locking=snapshot --multiprocess=4 --file-per-table --output-file=/tmp/myspace/dump_tableexport.log schemaName

And my current directory: /tmp/myspace $

All the files wrote out here.

Answer (score 1):

To export database by using Mysql workbench version: 6.2.3:

```
mysqldbexport --server=username:password@localhost --export=DATA --bulk-insert testSchema --output-file=D:/tmp/dump.sql
```